# Nan results when iterating using sin and cos functions

Tags: c++

I'm compiling this program using Code::Blocks 10.05 however normally I will get about 10 iterations done before it starts producing Nan in every single output. I was wondering if this is a problem caused by using the cos and sin functions and if there was a decent work around to avoid this?

I have to produce a lot of iterates because I am working on a project for University so it has to be accurate too. I looked up a few articles about how to avoid using sin and cos though I need to follow a few formulas rigorously otherwise the results I produce may be inaccurate so I'm not sure whether to compromise.

```
    struct Particle // Need to define what qualities our particle has
{
   double dPosition;
   double dAngle;

};

Particle Subject;

void M1(double &x, double &y) //Defines movement if particle doesn't touch inner   boundary
{
    x = x + 2*y;
}

double d = 0.25; //This can and will be changed when I need to find a distance between
                // the two cricles at a later stage


void M2(double &x,double &y, double d) //Defines movement of a particle if it impacts the inner boundary
{
    double z = asin(-(sin(y)+d*cos(x + y))/0.35);
    double y1 = y;
    y = asin(-0.35*sin(z) + d*cos(x + y + 2*z));
    x = y + y1 + x + 2*z;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Please tell me where you want this particle to start positions-wise? (Between 0 and 2PI" << endl;
    cin >> Subject.dPosition;
    cout << "Please tell me the angle that you would like it to make with the normal? (Between 0 and PI/2)" << endl;
    cin >> Subject.dAngle;
    cout << "How far would you like the distances of the two middle circles to be?" << endl;
    double d;
    cin >> d;

    // These two functions are to understand where the experiment begins from.
    // I may add a function to change where the circle starts however I will use radius = 0.35 throughout

    cout << "So position is: " << Subject.dPosition << endl;
    cout << "And angle with the normal is: " << Subject.dAngle <<endl;

    int n=0;
    while (n <= 100) //This is used to iterate the process and create an array of Particle data points
    {               // in order to use this data to build up Poincare diagrams.

    {
        while (Subject.dPosition > 2*M_PI)
            Subject.dPosition = Subject.dPosition - 2*M_PI;
    }
    {
        if (0.35 >= abs(0.35*cos(Subject.dPosition + Subject.dAngle)+sin(Subject.dAngle))) //This is the condition of hitting the inner boundary
            M2(Subject.dPosition, Subject.dAngle, d); //Inner boundary collision
        else
            M1(Subject.dPosition, Subject.dAngle); // Outer boundary collision
    };
    cout << "So position is: " << Subject.dPosition << endl;
    cout << "And angle with the normal is: " << Subject.dAngle <<endl;
    n++;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm putting my money on the `asin()` function being the problem. Arcsin is not defined for all inputs. And by problem I mean it's behaving correctly, but the result is undesired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value is outside of [-1,+1] and passed to asin(), the result will be nan

If you need to check for Nan, try the following

```
if( value != value ){
    printf("value is nan\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I managed to fix it and add in some if loops to sort out when it drifts below -1 or above 1.

Answer (score 3):

`Nan` is shown in c++ as an indication of infinite, zero devision, and some other variations of non representable numbers.

**Edit**:

As pointed by Matteo Itallia, `inf` is used for infinite/zero division. I found these approaches:

```
template<typename T>
inline bool isnan(T value) {
    return value != value;
}

// requires #include <limits>
template<typename T>
inline bool isinf(T value) {
    return std::numeric_limits<T>::has_infinity &&
        value == std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity();
}
```

Reference: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/588254-how-check-double-inf-nan

Comment: Actually, zero division will produce `Inf` (unless the dividend is `NaN` itself).

Comment: @MatteoItalia thanks for pointing it out; I've posted an edit.